# Moving a domain controller to another disk

Tags: windows, domain-controller, clone, clonezilla

Considering whether or not to move my domain controller to another disk (SSD) or not as in looking at Resource Manager the disk I/O appears to be the bottleneck for performance.

In the research I'm in the midst of doing I came across [this article](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH109743.html) which states that:

> Microsoft secures Domain Controllers by locking them to a disk
>   signature

Now, I'm not planning on using GHOST (rather Clonezilla) but the basic premise remains the same.

Can anyone confirm if this article is accurate, with sources if possible? If it is are there any workarounds?

Comment: 1. I've never heard that before and can't find any documentation or information from Microsoft that supports that claim from Symantec. 2. In all of my years of supporting AD I've never seen disk performance issues on a DC. What else is running on the DC? What other Roles, Features, or applications are installed on the DC? 3. My first suggestion would be to troubleshoot the disk I/O issue and determine what's at the root of it and whether or not it can be resolved.

Comment: It's an old server and I'm just trying to squeeze some more life out of it. I'm probably going to update the RAM as well while I'm at it. If I can spend €250 or so on it IMHO it'll be money well spent. Thanks for searching for the docs, that makes two of us that can't find anything from MSFT on that claim...

Comment: Never had a Problem cloning DCs to new disks. In most cases I had to set the new volume signature in DFS (or FRS if it's older) with the Registry Key mentioned in the logged event (if appliciable).